# I want to center the text of h1 and p tag in page in css

Tags: html, css

This is the html file:

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
}

.green {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>
```

I want to set the all text centered of individual div height. Means first the text of h1 will appear and just below of it the text of paragraph tag will appear. the space from upper portion to h1 tag and the space from ending of p tag to lower portion have to same.

I am newbie.please help me.

Comment: the title has nothing to do with your issue

Comment: If I understood correctly you want them to be vertical aligned? if so then, add flex-position: column to .green and .orange https://jsfiddle.net/yuLLxp1z/1/

Comment: I don't know how to add it. Can u tell me the code of that?

Comment: Hey Julian , your code solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Hope it helps!

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
}

.green {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Please be sure to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 250px;

}
p {
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  right: 480px;

}

.green {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>

<div class="orange">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error deserunt, labore explicabo, beatae vitae atque? Explicabo suscipit quod molestiae.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi reprehenderit, praesentium commodi illo hic ex nisi cumque aperiam placeat accusamus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can be how to set h1 like the script below, then also on p can use the script as below in the css script